# Pass Model to ViewModel on button click Xamarin MVVM

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm

I'm using Xamarin (MVVM) and I have a button which display data from `UserSelectionList`(model)

XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="userOne" 
                                            CommandParameter="{x:Reference userOne}"
                                            Text="{Binding UserSelectionList[0].Abbreviation}" 
                                            Command="{Binding ButtonSelectedCommand}"
                                            TextColor="White" 
                                            HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                                            VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                            BorderWidth="1"
                                            FontSize="92"
                                            HeightRequest="320"
                                            WidthRequest="320"
                                            Grid.Row="1"
                                            Grid.Column="0"
                                        />
```

`UserSelectionViewModel` model

```
public class UserSelectionViewModel
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see I have a Command property to use Two-Way Binding so in my View Model I have something like:

```
 //Initialize viewmodel

   public UserSelectionPageViewModel()
    {
        _ = LoadItems();

    }


//Create an UserSelectionViewModel instance


   private ObservableCollection <UserSelectionViewModel> _userSelectionList = new ObservableCollection<UserSelectionViewModel>();

    public ObservableCollection<UserSelectionViewModel> UserSelectionList
    {
        get { return _userSelectionList; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _userSelectionList, value, nameof(UserSelectionList)); }
    }




public ICommand ButtonSelectedCommand
    {
        get { return new Command(async x => await SelectedButton(x as Button)); }
    }




 // Fill UserSelectionList

private async Task LoadItems()
        {
            try

            {
              
                var userList = await UserHelper.LoadUsers();
               
                UserSelectionList = new ObservableCollection<UserSelectionViewModel>(userList);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

 //Assign UserSelectionViewModel to UserSelectionList

    private async Task<bool> SelectedButton(Button button)
    {
        var a = "";
        return true;
    }
```

My question is: How can I bind my `UserSelectionList[0]`  and access that model in my `ViewModel` `SelectedButton` method? Regards

Comment: This code breaks my brain. What is `UserSelectionList`? Collection? Is there some `ItemsControl` of `ListBox` outside of the `Button`? Why `async` method without `await` inside? Is current code doesn't work? Compile error? Exception? Nothing happens? Passing `Button` to a `CommandParameter` breaks MVVM as you mustn't pass any View items to the ViewModel but why do you need it? Please fill the question with more code and more details.

Comment: why wouldn't you just do `CommandParameter="{Binding UserSelectionList[0]}"`

Comment: and how should I receive in the ViewModel? @Jason

Comment: use `Command<T>` to pass a parameter of type `T`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `UserSelectionViewModel` as follow :

```
public class UserSelectionViewModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

    public ICommand ButtonSelectedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command((e) =>
            {
                var item = (e as UserSelectionViewModel);
                // logic on item
                Console.WriteLine(item.UserName);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Then create **ViewModel** to set some special data :

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<UserSelectionViewModel> UserSelectionList { set; get; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        UserSelectionList = new ObservableCollection<UserSelectionViewModel>();
        UserSelectionList.Add(new UserSelectionViewModel() { UserName = "1", Abbreviation = "button one" });
        UserSelectionList.Add(new UserSelectionViewModel() { UserName = "2", Abbreviation = "button two" });
        UserSelectionList.Add(new UserSelectionViewModel() { UserName = "3", Abbreviation = "button three" });
        UserSelectionList.Add(new UserSelectionViewModel() { UserName = "4", Abbreviation = "button four" });
        UserSelectionList.Add(new UserSelectionViewModel() { UserName = "5", Abbreviation = "button five" });
        UserSelectionList.Add(new UserSelectionViewModel() { UserName = "6", Abbreviation = "button six" });

    }
}
```

Now **Xaml** code also need to modify a little :

```
<Button Text="{Binding UserSelectionList[0].Abbreviation}"
        Command="{Binding UserSelectionList[0].ButtonSelectedCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding UserSelectionList[0]}"/>
```

Then when click button will receive the data of each `UserSelectionViewModel` .

[image]

Output :

```
07-28 10:34:24.307 I/mono-stdout(12600): 1
07-28 10:34:25.483 I/mono-stdout(12600): 1
07-28 10:34:26.452 I/mono-stdout(12600): 1
```

**In addition** , if `Button` is inside `ListView` , also can get the `UserSelectionViewModel` . Sample code as follow :

```
<ListView  x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee" x:Name="Item"
                             Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="{Binding UserName}"
                               TextColor="#f35e20" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Abbreviation}"
                               HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                               TextColor="#503026" />
                        <Button Text="{Binding Abbreviation}"
                                Command="{Binding ButtonSelectedCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference Item}, Path=BindingContext}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```